# Can't Connect on postgresql pgpool "invalid backend response. Response does not replied with "R"

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I'm trying to connect on My pgpool install (3 Nodes)

I'm using a virtual IP adress to connect to my master server.
If i reach directly Postgresql, it works:

```
    psql -h *virtual IP* -U postgres -p 5432
```

but as soon as i try

```
    psql -h *virtual IP* -U postgres -p 5433
```

Server respond back:

```
    psql: ERROR:  authentication failed
    DÉTAIL : invalid backend response. Response does not replied with "R"
```

Note that when i type a wrong password, awnser from the serer is different.
I tried:

Setup pool_hba
Checking if md5 password is different in pool_passwd than in Postgresql
Restarting services
Trying to connect from a different User
Tried to set pool_passwd owner to postgres

What am i doing wrong ? My latest tests were good with 2 nodes.

Everything is working fine on postgresql, can connect from everywhere with postgres...

pg_hba:

```
    host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Thanks

Comment: What versions are you using?  What authentication method are you using?  It says something about md5, but is that what your pg_hba actually says?

Comment: And is your stored password stored in md5 format?  (md5 in pg_hba really means md5 or scram, not just exactly md5)

Comment: @jjanes i'm Using md5 and version 4.0.2, i added pg_hba line on my post

Comment: What about version of PostgreSQL?  Also, what is your OS?  Is it MacOS, which has some known problems with GSS (even if you aren't trying to use GSS)?

Comment: I'm currently on a Debian 10 VM, using postgresql 11. Not trying to use GSS :(

Comment: What if you use the real IP address?  I don't see how that could make a difference, but I don't know what else could cause the problem either.

Comment: Using the machine IP instead of the VIP is not working neither ;(

Comment: It works for me (postgres and pgpool2 both installed from Debian's apt repo, both on the same machine), so I think there is something peculiar about either your installation method, or your configuration.

Comment: Will look deeper into it so. Thx for the awnser anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to login through psql on the master replica first without using pgpool. In my case the postgres password was set to null/undefined. Therefore I got the same error message as you.

Hope that helps.